# How to share image on social media from ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I created a New Project in `ionic3`

In My Project; Firstly, I save the image into Database using PHP

Then I retrieve all images from database and display in ionic `photo.html` using `photo.ts`

It works successfully.But I need to add sharing options in ionic3.

If users click the share button, that particular image will share on users social media(fb, twitter, whatsapp). How to do this?

**Here is html code**

**photo.html**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>photo</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
<ion-grid>  
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
<ion-row align-items-stretch>
<ion-col col-12 col-md-6 align-self-stretch align-self-center  
approxItemHeight="457px">
             <ion-card class="card">
       <img src="http://xxxxxx.com/imgshare/{{item.img}}" height="200" 
width="200">
        <button ion-button color="lightText" 
(click)="share(item)">share</button>
</ion-card>      
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-item>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**photo.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-photo',
templateUrl: 'photo.html',
})
export class PhotoPage {
public items : Array<any> = [ ];  
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
public http: HttpClient, private socialSharing: SocialSharing) {
}
ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad PhotoPage');
}
   ionViewWillEnter() : void
{
  this.load();
}
load() : void
{
  this.http
  .get('http://xxxx.com/imgshare/retrieve.php')
  .subscribe((data : any) =>
  {
     console.dir(data);
     this.items = data;
     console.log(this.items[0].img);

  },
  (error : any) =>
  {
     console.dir(error);
  });
}
}
```

Comment: I have retrieve all images from db.Now Users need to share particular image (not all images) to their fb,whatsapp,twitter.How To do This?? @Utpaul

Comment: check my answer...

Comment: thank you,i solve that issues..any way your answer is also correct@Utpaul

Comment: welcome @vignesh. I was busy in last week sorry for late answer...

Comment: ok no pblm thanks once again @Utpaul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all you need to install `Social sharing` via two command following:**

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing
```

Then there are many way to share in different social site.

This will share the app via the action sheet to any app you choose.

```
share(index){
  this.socialSharing.share(index.img, null, null, null);
}
```

More details visit [medium link](https://medium.com/@mikeyny/easy-social-sharing-with-ionic-3-and-ionic-native-f2c42807f43c)

And also visit official site [official link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/)

Answer (score 1):

I used `Social sharing` then I used this method on my app.

```
share(data){
  this.socialSharing.share('',null,data.imgUrl,null);
}
```

and it's work for me.

Sorry about my English.